# Why is ActiveRecord trying to delete the row corresponding to an object when it's deleted from an array?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Inside an AR object class definition (I'm not sure that's relevant, but I'm including that info in case it is), I have a method that collects an array of other AR objects and selectively deletes some of them inside a loop. Essentially:

```
class SomeApplicationModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def user_method
    c_list = [array of c objects]
    p_list.each{|p|
      ... a bunch of logic to determine if c should be deleted
      c_list.delete(c)
    }
  end
end
```

When it hits c_list.delete(c), I get an error in the logs from a relation that includes c and p:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stagingdb/c_p`, CONSTRAINT `c_p_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cp_id`) REFERENCES `cs` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `cs` WHERE `cs`.`id` = 147:
```

Why is it trying to delete the record in the db that corresponds to c here (the stack trace pegs the .delete line as where the error is thrown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c_list` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of an `Array`, then `delete` will remove the value from the database.  You may want to check the value of `c_list.class`.  Depending on what you want to do, you could either use `to_a` to work with an `Array` or translate your filtering logic into a set of `ActiveRecord::Relation` methods.

Comment: I'll have to dig into it more, but it is definitely not an explicit relation. Is _list some sort of implicit relationship suffix (the actual variable names in the above are obscured, but they do actually end with _list)?

Comment: Can you share the actual code that is used in the `[array of c objects]` section?

Comment: Not directly. What I can say is that it's the output of a method on the SomeApplicationModel that returns either the results of C.find(list_of_ideas) or C.all, where C is the ActiveRecord class corresponding to c, and then the results of that method are copied into a new array with .clone(). That cloned array is what's being deleted from.

Comment: This led me down the right path. In fact, in AR3, SomeModel.all returns an array, but in AR4, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecords_Relation_SomeModel object (.find still returns an array in both cases). Is there documentation you know of that would point me in the right direction to figure out exactly why that changed and the right way to deal with that?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6a81ccd69d96f36f4322ef927191ab5a35e68d68#diff-2ea4047e83f40a075015865a491c82e7